# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running Mac OSX Mountain Lion

ruby:
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin12.1.0]

rails:
Rails 3.2.3

I have my config/enviroment/development.rb:

MyApp::Application.configure do

```
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
    user_name: "username",
    password: "password"
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}
end
```

This was working 2 weeks ago and the code has not been changed.
I have however since then upgraded to mountain lion.
We also added an extra hook for Git called staging but that should not have effected it.
After encountering this problem this morning
I added the line you see in the code that looks like this:

```
  openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

which I saw in another post about this issue. It did not work.

The action mailer is working fine on the testers, and production
servers, so we are now convinced this is an issue in regards to the upgrade to lion.

Thank you for your time.